# Prove that $a^{n+m}=a^{n}a^m$, for real numbers

Tags: calculus

How does one prove that
$$ a^{n+m} = a^{n}  a^{m} $$
for $a,n,m \in \mathbb R$.

I can prove this for integers but how can one prove this for real numbers?

Comment: What is your definition of $a^n$ for non-integer $n$?

Comment: Could it be $e^{n\log a}$... but then what of $a\leq 0$...

Comment: Then my question would be: How can we prove that $e^{n+m}=e^{n}e^{m}$

Comment: It will depend on what you are taking as given. You can easily prove this for rationals, and if you assume continuity, you can use the denseness of rationals in the reals to extend it to the reals.

Comment: Your statement is not true in general, because $a^{n}$ is not in general well-defined. You need either $a > 0$ or $n,m \in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 3):

You need $a > 0$ for this to make sense.

1. For $n, m$ integers, by induction
2. For rational $n, m$, use the definition that $a^{n/m} = \sqrt[m]{a^n}$, and reduce to case (1)
3. Extend to all real $n, m$ by continuity

Comment: You may need $ a \gt 0$

Comment: @Henry, thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If you meant for $a>0$, then

$$a^{n+m}=\exp\left[(n+m)\ln{a}\right]$$

Now use some knowledge of $\log$ to finish proving.

Comment: Then my question would be: How can we prove that $e^{n+m}=e^{n}e^{m}$

Comment: No, what is $e^{n\ln{a}}$?

Comment: Hint: It is $a^n$

Comment: @OlePetersen, *that* is a new question, which I'd be happy to answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Define

$$F(z) := x^{z+a}x^{-z}x^{-a} \qquad a,x,z \in \Bbb R$$

and assume $x > 0$. Then

$$F'(z) = 0$$

so $F(z)$ is a constant function, which means $F(z) = F(0)$ for all $z$. Now set $a = 0$ and we get

$$F(z) = x^z x^{-z} = F(0) = x^0 x^0 = 1 \iff x^z x^{-z} = 1 \iff x^{-z} = \frac{1}{x^z} \qquad (1)$$

Furthermore, we encounter

$$F(z) = x^{z+a}x^{-z}x^{-a} = F(0) = x^a x^{-a} \underset{(1)}{=} 1$$

Hence

$$F(z) = x^{z+a}x^{-z}x^{-a} = 1$$

which is

$$x^{z+a} = x^z x^a$$

Comment: I don't understand the second line where you diff. $z$.

Comment: Forget that, it was wrong. But nevertheless, $F'(z)=0$, if you use $x^z = e^{z \ln x}$.